# Chef cookbook upload using name in metadata.rb instead of the current working directory name

Tags: chef-infra

When using chef, I have the problem, I download the cookbook ceph-cookbook through git clone, the current working directory name is "**ceph-cookbook**", but the cookbook's name specified in metadata.rb is "**ceph**". Then I upload the cookbook to my chef-server using the name "**ceph**", I should manually change the directory name from "**ceph-cookbook**" to "**ceph**", that is so stupid!

So my question is that can I upload the ceph cookbook to my chef-server(**knife cookbook upload ceph**) using the name "ceph" without changing the name of working directory. I have been resorting to the options of knife command, but failed.

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify path for your cookbooks that you want to upload with:

```
-o PATH:PATH, --cookbook-path PATH:PATH
The directory in which cookbooks are created. This can be a colon-separated path.
```

More info about options for `knife cookook` command you can [find here](https://docs.chef.io/knife_cookbook.html#upload).

In your case it would be:

```
knife cookbook upload ceph -o cookbooks/ceph-cookbook
```

Comment: `-o` sets the base path for cookbooks, so your command would then be looking to upload `cookbooks/ceph-cookbook/ceph`

Comment: Damnn, tnx for the update. Than using Berkshelf, or any other cookbook dependency manager is only alternative.